# Powershell: BeginInvoke Parameter Count Mismatch

Tags: forms, powershell, begininvoke

I am trying to create a powershell script that pulls up a simple GUI form, displays "Loading..." in the title bar while it takes about 10-20 seconds to load the data, then finally change the title to "Please choose from the following options..." after loading.

I've been following [this guide](http://poshcode.org/5520) pretty much down to the letter. So far everything works, except for the fact that I get a "Parameter Count Mismatch" error when I execute this line:

`$objListbox.BeginInvoke(
    [Action[string]] { param($Message) $objListbox.Items.Add = $Message },
    $MyMessage
)`

Basically what I'm trying to do is load up about two thousand names into a multiselect listbox, then allow users to select the names they want to import elsewhere.  So far everything works, I just have to hit continue on the Powershell ISE editor, but I'd like to get rid of this error all together.

Answer (score 0):

`BeginInvoke` is rather older than generics in the .NET framework, and considerably older than the delegate `Action<T>`. Specifically you cannot pass an instance of `Action<T>` to `BeginInvoke`.

Try casting to `System.Delegate` instead.